# What's the font of the LinkedIn #OpenToWork badge?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I'm trying to identify the exact font LinkedIn uses for the #OpenToWork and #Hiring badges, which are placed on the profile pictures.

[image: #OpenToWork badge taken from a LinkedIn video]
[image: Extracted text of the #Hiring badge]

So far I tried my own best guesses as well as different font identifiers ([WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), [Fontspring Matcherator](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator))that yielded close matches but seemingly not the exact font. Typefaces that came close but I ruled out eventually are Tenon, Akkurat, Work Sans, Public Sans and Hanken Grotesk. The [LinkedIn brand font](https://brand.linkedin.com/content/brand/global/en_us/index/visual-identity/typography) Source Sans also doesn't match.

Letters that to my eye look characteristic are the G, K and R.

The #OpenToWork Screenshot is taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/p_WSSV072tE). I couldn't find an example for the #Hiring tag, and for privacy reasons I didn't upload a screenshot from a real account. Instead I tried my best extracting the glyphs.

Comment: It's similar to [Brenner Sans](https://www.typotheque.com/fonts/brenner-sans) but not close enough to make that an answer -- the dissimilarities are rather annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is a month old now, but I was looking for this font today, too. I'm  pretty sure it's Carlito Bold, a Google font. Cheers!